# VS2010 Program won't connect to MYSQL from local SQL Server Computer

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server

my problem here is very weird compared to other that I found on this forum. The VB program is created with VS2010 from computer "A". It work perfectly. Connection to SQL Server and MYSQL DB. But when I copy the whole file to computer "B" where SQL Server is installed and is used by the program I mentioned before. SO I open with the VS 2010 and debug the program. This time the program can't connect to database. Error " No connection to database. Error trying to connect to user "user" ". Where "user" is the name of user.

FYI, everything maintain the same, IP, username, password, database. Only the location I open the proggram. Besides, I also check the firewall, mssql,ssma but still no connection.

What could cause this type of problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to change the IP to localhost.

Comment: Still the same problem. No connection to Db. :(

Comment: So, do you get a particular error number back?

Comment: Also, the user you added to MySQL, it should be `user` `@` `<somehost>` what host did you add? Also, what are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: yes its this.
"no connection possible to DB: an error link to network or specific authorisation when trying to make a connection to sql server. The server is unavailable or inaccessible.Verify that the name is correct and the  server is configure to authorise distance connection.(provider: Named Pipes Provider,error: 40-Impossible open  a connection to sql server)".
that is the error box. But I still don't get the reason why.

Comment: So, on one server you say MySQl, on the other SQL server.. which is you are trying to connect to?

Comment: actually the program uses both. sql server as main, and mysql as backup if anything when wrong. the user name is `user` and the db is `mit` but the specific hostname i'm not sure as isn't me that write the program. But I have acces to the SSMS. please guide me to solve the problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, I know in mysql, you have three normal things that have to match for authentication to work. 1. user name 2. password. 3. host.  I've had a look at SQL server, it doesn't seem to have the same sort of authentication system. You need to make sure that the `user` you are using to connect exists on server B, and has the access you need . It's not my forte' but there seems to be plenty of information about user management here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545450.aspx

Comment: Can you connect via SQL Management Studio from the SQL host machine using the connection settings and credentials the program uses?

Comment: I tried follow based on what i understand as i'm new in this type of stuff. Yes, the`user` exist in the DB as i could connect to it from another computer. But what do you mean by `SQL host machine using the connection settings and credentials the program uses` ? I'm on the computer where the sql server is installed for the uses of the program that I'm having problem now. I can acces the SQL Management Studio.